# How do I remove entire strings if they contain a matched pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Say I have the following string -

```
vector <- "this is a string of text containing stuff. something.com thisthat@co.uk and other stuff with something.anything"
```

I would like to remove a string if it contains `@` or `.` , so I would like to remove `something.com`, `thisthat@co.uk` and `something.anything`. I do not want to remove `stuff` because it's the end of a sentence and does not contain `.`. Ideally I would like to be able to use the `%>%` pipe to do this.

Comment: The R package "tokenizers" has functions that will tokenize in various ways which can be combined. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tokenizers/vignettes/introduction-to-tokenizers.html

Comment: @JohnGarland Thanks, that is good to know. I am actually doing a key word analysis and passing the string to the unest_tokens() function in tidytext package. However when I get the most frequent words, there is still words that don't make sense so I'm trying to remove them "before" using the tidytext functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 gsub(" ?\\w+[.@]\\S+", "", vector)

[1] "this is a string of text containing stuff. and other stuff with"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the (much more terse/simple) `gsub` method:

```r
gre <- gregexpr("[^ ]+[.@][^ ]+", vector)
regmatches(vector, gre)
# [[1]]
# [1] "something.com"      "thisthat@co.uk"     "something.anything"
regmatches(vector, gre) <- ""
vector
# [1] "this is a string of text containing stuff.   and other stuff with "
```

This has the advantage of being able to replace them arbitrarily. Granted, we're just replacing them here with `""`, so this is a little overkill, but if you need to *change* the values somehow (change each substring), then this is a more powerful mechanism.